# How $f$ in the below PDE changes based on $x$ and $y$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In this equation quasi-linear eq $\Big\{\exp(f(x,y))\dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} + \dfrac{y}{x} \dfrac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} = 1\Big\}$ how $f$ changes based on $x$ and $y$ analytically? Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin(f)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \dfrac{y}{x} \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y} = 1$$

NOTE : This was the original equation written in the first edition of the question. Latter on, the OP modified the equation replacing $\sin(f)$ by $\exp(f)$. As a consequence my answer below doesn't match. An updated answer is in : [Solve a first order PDE using the method of characteristics ($ \exp(u)u_x + \frac{y}{x}u_y = 1$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4141675/solve-a-first-order-pde-using-the-method-of-characteristics-expuu-x-fra)

Original answer to the original PDE :

Charpit-Lagrange characteristic ODEs
$$\frac{dx}{\sin(f)}=\frac{dy}{y/x}=\frac{df}{1}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dx}{\sin(f)}=\frac{df}{1}\quad\implies\quad dx=\sin(f)df$ :
$$\cos(f)+x=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\frac{dy}{y/x}=\frac{df}{1}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dy}{y}=\frac{df}{c_1-\cos(f)}$
$$\ln|y|-\frac{2}{\sqrt{(c_1)^2-1}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1+1}{c_1-1}}\tan\left(\frac{f}{2} \right) \right)=c_2$$
General solution of the PDE on the form of implicit equation $c_2=F(c_1)$ :
$$\ln|y|-\frac{2}{\sqrt{(c_1)^2-1}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{c_1+1}{c_1-1}}\tan\left(\frac{f}{2} \right) \right)=F\big(\cos(f)+x \big)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function (to be determined according to some boundary conditions which are missing in the wording of the question).
$$\boxed{\ln|y|-\frac{2}{\sqrt{(\cos(f)+x)^2-1}}\arctan\left(\sqrt{\frac{\cos(f)+x+1}{\cos(f)+x-1}}\tan\left(\frac{f}{2} \right) \right)=F\big(\cos(f)+x \big)}$$

In the general case the above solution (implicit equation) cannot be transformed to an explicit equation $f(x,y)$. This depends on the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your $f = f(x,y)$, then it is mostly linear other than the first coefficient, which is nonlinear in the unknown $f(x,y)$, which would make this a quasilinear PDE. I am also assuming that your second term is $\frac{y}{x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}.$
As for the change in behaviour, this looks complicated to solve analytically. It could be useful to put into use a numerical scheme and see how the plot looks to gauge a particular form of solution, perhaps finite differences. Hope this helps!