# Solve a first order PDE using the method of characteristics ($ \exp(u)u_x + \frac{y}{x}u_y = 1$)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics

I'm solving the PDE:

$$\exp(u)u_x + \frac{y}{x}u_y = 1$$

With characteristics given by

$$\frac{dx}{\exp(u)} = \frac{dy}{y/x} = \frac{du}{1} $$

Giving a corresponding solution of

$$c1 = x^2 -2y^2\exp(u)\\ c2 = u-\frac{y^2}{2x}$$

Thus

$$u(x,t) = \frac{y^2}{2x}+ F(x^2 - 2y\exp(u))$$  .

Is this right?

Comment: If I take $F$ to be the zero function, then $u=y^2/2x$ should satisfy the PDE, but it doesn't. I don't understand how you solved the system of ODEs.

Comment: @Dimitri_896. Your characteristic equations $c_1$ and $c_2$ are not correct. Apparently you integrate the ODEs without separating the variables. For example one cannot integrate $\frac{dy}{y/x}$ because the function $\frac{1}{y/x}=\frac{x}{y}$ is not a function of $x$ only. Don't forget : Separate the variables before integrating.

Answer (score 1):

$$\exp(u)u_x + \frac{y}{x}u_y = 1$$
I agree with $\frac{dx}{\exp(u)} = \frac{dy}{y/x} = \frac{du}{1} $

First characteristic from solving $\frac{dx}{\exp(u)} = \frac{du}{1} $
$$e^u-x=c_1$$
Second characteristic from solving $\frac{dx}{\exp(u)} = \frac{dy}{y/x} \quad\implies\quad \frac{dx}{x+c_1} = x\frac{dy}{y}\quad\implies\quad \frac{dx}{x(x+c_1)} = \frac{dy}{y}$
$$\frac{x+c_1}{x}y^{c_1}=c_2$$
General solution on the form of implicit equation : $\frac{x+c_1}{x}y^{c_1}=F(c_1)$
$$\frac{e^u}{x}y^{e^u-x}=F(e^u-x)$$